# Yii2: Glyphicons not appearing in gridview after Yii upgrade/move

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, glyphicons

I can't figure out what's wrong. After moving my site and upgrading Yii to a more recent version, the glyphicons no longer display properly in GridView.

I'm using Yii 2.0.29 with PHP 7.3.

My bootstrap line in `composer.json` file is

`"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0"`

Here's a screenshot of what appears

[image: Gridview Screenshot]

Comment: Like a solution go to the Bootstrap homepage and download the full .zip file. Extract the four font files from there to your fonts directory and edit AppAsset to include those files. I met this on my project recently, personally i switched to Font Awesome icons.

Comment: Thank you. That's just what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm still pretty frustrated in my attempts to fix this. I downloaded the 4 font files into `/vendor/bower/bootstrap/fonts`. No effect. AppAsset allows me to define basePath, baseUrl, css, js, and depends. How would I create a link to the new fonts?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because of bootstrap 4!

[> See the Migrating to v4, Components](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components)

You can do one of the following:

- download https://glyphicons.com/ and attach it to your assets.
- change icons to what you want, see [gridview buttons](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn#$buttons-detail)
- or change the style (I prefer it):
  for example I change it to fontawsome,

```css
.glyphicon {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
}

.glyphicon-pencil::before {
    content: "\f044";
}

.glyphicon-trash::before {
    content: "\f2ed";
}

.glyphicon-eye-open::before {
    content: "\f06e";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add old bootstrap.css's @font-face and its glyphicons class to your new bootstrap.css . I mean you have old bootstrap in bower-asset and new bootstrap in your npm-asset and you have to first copy bower-asset/bootstrap/fonts folder to your npm-asset/bootstrap/dist/ and open npm-assets bootstrap.css and add old bootstrap.css's @font-face object and glyphicon's all object there
then and check it !!!!!!!